# How to escape special characters on saving/retrieving data from Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Assume a value has all windows special characters including "-" and it cannot be inserted directly to Mongo.

1. where i can find the mongo db special character restrictions?
2. How to escape while saving or retrieving?

example, do we need to pass the value within brackets ([...])? how to insert and retrieve the record with special character.

Thanks.

Comment: What client / driver are you using to insert your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
MongoCollection.findOne(query, parameter)
```

resolved the problem.

Query and parameter explicite:

```
MongoCollection.findOne("{ empName: # }", empName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Values in MongoDB can be any UTF-8 string. Escaping would be the responsibility of your client program. Depending on which client program / language driver you are using, you would need to use the necessary escape character(s) for that language.

Since you mentioned that you're using Jongo, that means that you're using Java and the mongo-java-driver. In Java, you can just use the unicode escape sequence for the character you're trying to use. For example, \u2014 is the em-dash character.

For example:

```
DB db = new MongoClient().getDB("test");
Jongo jongo = new Jongo(db);
MongoCollection collection = jongo.getCollection("mycollection");
collection.insert("{fieldWithDash: 'x-y', fieldWithEmDash: 'x\u2014y'}");
Test test = collection.findOne("{fieldWithEmDash: 'x\u2014y'}").as(Test.class);
System.out.println(test);
```

Comment: We are using Jongo API

Comment: MongoCollection.findOne(query, parameter) resolved the problem. Query and parameter is "{ empName: # }", empName